# Serverless Appsync IdentityPoolRoleMap deployment error

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am using "serverless-appsync-plugin" for generationg Appsync Api and Cogntio Userpool and Federated Identities, everything is getting properly deployed and is working fine except the "IdentityPoolRoleMap", Its giving the below error

"**ServerlessError: An error occurred: IdentityPoolRoleMap - null (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalFailure;)**"

Adding the sample of IdentityPoolRoleMap

```
IdentityPoolRoleMap:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
      Properties:
        IdentityPoolId: { Ref: IdentityPool }
        Roles:
          unauthenticated: { Fn::GetAtt: [ UnauthRole, Arn ]}
          authenticated: { Fn::GetAtt: [ AuthRole, Arn ]}
```

Note: IdentityPool,UnauthRole and AuthRole are properly created.

Comment: Do you get the same error every time you retry `serverless deploy`? Can you share the request ID?

Comment: Could you try adding quotes like this sample, just to rule that out? https://forum.serverless.com/t/aws-serverless-identitypoolroleattachment/4709/2 And if that doesn't work, reach out to AWS support with your stack arn from the cloudformation console.